# Root of the quadratic equation while solving limit

Tags: limits, continuity, quadratics, quadratic-forms

Let α and β be the distinct roots of  $ax^2+bx+c=0$
then $(x-α)(x-β)=0$ is same as $a(x-α)(x-β)=0$
When we solve questions of limit like
$$\lim_{x \to α} \frac{(1−\cos⁡(ax^2+bx+c))}{(x−α)^2}$$
why we write $a(x-α)(x-β)=0$ instead of $(x-α)(x-β)=0$.

Comment: where is $n$ in your formula?

Comment: Sorry that was by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question about why we factor $ax^2+bx+c=0$ as 
$a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$ instead of $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$ is that $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ is not the correct factorization.

If you multiply out
$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta$, we observe that the $x^2$ term doesn't have the right coefficient.  We should have $ax^2$ and only have $x^2$.  Therefore, if we multiply though by $a$, we'll get the correct factorization.

Basically, $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\not=ax^2+bx+c$ because the coefficients can't possibly match (unless $a=1$).

However, $a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$ has the same zeros and same leading coefficient as $ax^2+bx+c$, so it is the same polynomial.

You can't just simplify the fractions ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ - if they even are fractions) because then you'll end up with coefficients on the $x$'s.  For example
$$
\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{6}(2x-1)(3x-2).
$$

Also, be careful not to confuse the *equation*
$$
ax^2+bx+c=0
$$
with the polynomial
$$
ax^2+bx+c.
$$
In the equation, you are free to multiply or divide as you choose (since you'll also be multiplying or dividing zero, which doesn't change anything) while with the polynomial, if you multiply by $t$ you must also divide by $t$ to balance.

Comment: usually in such cases $α$ $β$ will be in rational form so a will appear when you simpllify

Comment: When you simplify, observe that you're changing the coefficient of $x$ as well!

Comment: Take a euation $4x^2+3x-1=0$  in this case $α=-1$ and $β=1/4$ so $(x+1)(x-1/4)=0$ is same as  $4(x+1)(x-1/4)=0$

Comment: The equations are equivalent, the polynomials aren't.

Comment: Thanks I got it

Answer (score 1):

you must write $$\lim_{x\to \alpha}\frac{(1-\cos(a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta))}{(x-\alpha)^2}$$
the result is $$\frac{1}{2}a^2(\alpha-\beta)^2$$ wich can obtained e.g. by L'Hospital.

Comment: answer should be $a^2 (α−β)^2/2$  I know answer but why we should write $ a(x−α)(x−β)=0 $ instead of  $(x−α)(x−β)=0$ that is my question

Comment: since your quaratic equation has the form $$ax^2+bx+c$$

Comment: @MichaelBurr That is my question why that $a^2$ is in answer. If i use $(x−α)(x−β)=0$ instead of $a(x−α)(x−β)=0$ that $a^2$ will not appear in answer